# Using Eigrp to connect a large Network, is there a max to Eigrp entries ?

Tags: cisco

I recently was working on this project designed by myself and i was forming neighbors with the routers via EIGRP. At a point the routers failed to form neighbors, and I was suspecting that Eigrp might have max entries. I need help to connect as many networks as possible.

Although it looks impossible from my simulator, I need your experience on this one. Feel free to ask for the packet tracer file in case you need to personally work on it. Below is the number of eigrp neighbors both dynamic and directly connected on the Engineering router
Thanks[image]

Comment: You have probably exceeded what your simulator can do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can have a look at your pkt file. Also EIGRP is very much capable of handling somewhere between 5000-10000 router without any specific issues although if he number goes up you might want to consider BGP as it is for larger networks (WAN).

Meanwhile, you can try your simulation on GNS and see if it works.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

See Configuration wise there is no limit for setting no. of networks in EIGRP. However the number of routing table entries that a particular cisco router can hold varies from model to model, depending upon the router ram size, its in the order of thousands/hundreds of thousands of routes, so its not a thing to worry about.

Also, Packet Tracer Software is buggy and unreliable, use GNS3 emulator for large routing tables and reliable emulation. Both OSPF and EIGRP can work on 5000-10,000 routes without showing any performance degradation. Beyond this number the network is too large for these protocols and these protocols should be avoided in such a network. We have BGP for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the mid-size low-end models like Cat9300 can hold some 5000-8000 routes.
If possible you should consider using stub network functionallity and perhaps summarization to minimize routingtable.